# Call a function while setting value of a declarement

Tags: c++, c, function, operators

I want to call a function while setting a value.
For example:

```
int i;
i = 123; //Here i want to call a function. 
//Want to do this:
//i = 123;func();
//But i do not want to do like this.
```

Can i add a new operator that can do this?

```
int i;
i $ 123; //set i = 123 and call a function.
```

Comment: Is `i` a global variable?  How does it affect `func`?

Comment: I don't understand. What's wrong with doing `i = 123; func();`?

Comment: Also, do you know about the comma operator? `int i; i = 123, func();`

Comment: Do you mean like property getter/setter functions?

Comment: Could you try explaining again what you are trying to achieve in a different way? Because currently it is very unclear.

Comment: OK clearly i want to call a function after setting a value to a declarement.
I can not include func(); directly into project so i think i must overload = operator but i do not know how to do, or creating new operator like =.

Comment: Primitive types not work with overloads, I think. Usihng `class` it ist possible `C C::operator= (C param) { .. }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to trigger a function call on assignment, you can wrap the type in a class that overrides the assignment operator; note that you may [want to override more than just assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), this is just an example and not a style guide :)

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> class wrap
{
private:
  T value;
  void (*fn)();
public:
  wrap(void (*_fn)()) { fn=_fn; }
  T& operator=(const T& in) { value = in; fn(); return value;}

  operator T() { return value; }
};

void func() {
  std::cout << "func() called!" << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  wrap<int> i(func);
  i=5;                           // Assigns i and calls func()
  std::cout << i << std::endl;   // i is still usable as an int
}

> Output: 
>   func() called!
>   5
```

Comment: Hmm, it is not what i want but it is very good, in main() it does not call the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to pass `123` to a function and then store the return value of that function in `i`, like so:

```
int i = func(123);
```

For this to work, your `func` should look something like this:

```
int func(int val)
{
  // ...
  return /* ... */;
}
```

But it's hard to decipher your question, so this may be completely not what you want.

Comment: No. I can do like you do but i must not use function directly.
int i = 123; //This must set i to 123 and call a function which included in project.I think this can only works if i declare new operator. But i do not know how to do.

Comment: @user2399300 That cannot be done and I can't see why you would want to do it. The closest you can get is have something like `int i = func();` and have `func` return the value `123`. But if it always returns the same value, I can't see why you'd have it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can not overload `$`, in fact `$` is not an C++ operator. (Even, if It was an operator, it's not in the list of overload able operators).

Moreover, you can not overload any operator for `int`, you must overload operator for classes.

Try this simple way if you want to have an uniform method:

```
class Integer {
    int x;
public:
    Integer(int x = 0) : x(x) {}

    operator int() {
        return x;
    }

    void operator^(int i) {
        x = i;
        func();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Integer i;
    i ^ 123;

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I want to create a NEW operator like $,or overload existing operator. So this cannot be done?

Comment: @user2399300 furthermore, you cannot create new operators.

Comment: I wrote a code for you, it overload `^` (instead of `$`) which do as same as you want.

Comment: The new edit is very good , but @Joachim Isaksson wrote similar answer before. But your new answer and his answer is really very good and related my question best. Thank you both!
(Sorry so does not allow checking useful or not)